# How to stub rand in rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm using Ruby 2.3.4 and rspec 3.6.0.

I'm writing a test for an object that uses `rand(10000..99999)`. I can't find any docs on `rand` to see what object it's a part of. I tried stubbing `Kernel`, `Object`, and `Random` (see below) but none of my attempts resulted in `rand` being stubbed for the object.

```
allow(Kernel).to receive(rand).and_return(12345)
allow(Object).to receive(rand).and_return(12345)
allow(Random).to receive(rand).and_return(12345)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`rand` is indeed implemented in the `Kernel` module. However, when calling the method inside your code, the method receiver is actually your own object.

Assume the following class:

```
class MyRandom
  def random
    rand(10000..99999)
  end
end

my_random = MyRandom.new
my_random.random
# => 56789
```

When calling `my_random.random`, the receiver (i.e. the object on which the method is called on) of the `rand` method is again the `my_random` instance since this is the object being `self` in the `MyRandom#random` method.

When testing this, you can this stub the `rand` method on this instance:

```
describe MyRandom do
  let(:subject) { described_class.new }

  describe '#random' do
    it 'calls rand' do
      expect(subject).to receive(:rand).and_return(12345)
      expect(subject.random).to eq 12345
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Interesting, I had no idea ruby assigns `rand` called on it's own to the object it's called. This worked, thank you!!

Comment: This is the same for all modules. If you include the module in a class, it's the methods are called on the class instance. `Kernel` is no different here. It's only "special" in that the `Kernel` module is included in all Objects by default, allowing its methods to be called everywhere. Since it is still a normal module, you can however overwrite its methods per class the same way you could for any other methods (although you should be careful doing so).

Answer (score 6):

This works:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Object).to receive(:rand).and_return(12345)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it can be hard to stub objects that are deep within another. So I find this approach helps simplify things:

```
class Worker
  def self.rand(*args)
    # Calls the actual rand method
    Kernel.rand(*args)
  end

  def perform
    # Calls private method rand -> Worker.rand
    rand(1..5)
  end

  private

  def rand(*args)
    self.class.rand(*args)
  end
end
```

This allows us to stub with ease:

```
allow(Worker).to receive(:rand).and_return(2)

expect(Worker.new.perform).to eq 2
```